# what is difference between 'SCRIPT_FILENAME' and 'REQUEST_FILENAME' on RewriteModule?

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

what is difference between `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `REQUEST_FILENAME` in mod_rewrite ?

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQEUST_FILENAME}
```

Answer (score 5):

> The variables SCRIPT_FILENAME and REQUEST_FILENAME contain the same
>   value - the value of the filename field of the internal request_rec
>   structure of the Apache HTTP Server. The first name is the commonly
>   known CGI variable name while the second is the appropriate
>   counterpart of REQUEST_URI (which contains the value of the uri field
>   of request_rec).

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html